# Histogram Upsize issues

Tags: java, methods, compiler-errors, histogram

I have solved the compile issues and have run into issues with my upsize histogram method. It seems that my 'copy' section of the method isn't working for some reason. Any ideas? I'll mark it within the code.

Here is the entirety of the code I have written.

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Project5
{
    static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 10;

public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
{
    if (args.length < 1) die("You must type the dictionary filename on cmd line.\n");

    // Here we have declared an int array, called 'histogram' with initial capacity of 0
    // it is a freq counter to word lengths in the file 

    int[] histogram = new int[0];

    // Here we have declared an array of String to read the dictionary file into. We use BufferedReader (not Scanner).
    // With each word read in, examine it's length and update word length frequency histogram accordingly

    String[] wordList = new String[INITIAL_CAPACITY];
    int wordCount = 0;
    BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(args[0]) );
    while ( infile.ready() ) // i.e. while there are more lines of text in the file
    {
            String word = infile.readLine();

            // YOUR CODE HERE TO CHECK TO SEE IF WORDLIST IS FULL
            // IF SO YOU MUST DO AN UPSIZE JUST LIKE LAB#6
            if ( wordCount == wordList.length ) 
                wordList = upSizeArr( wordList );

            // YOUR CODE HERE to add this word to your list
            String newWord = infile.next(); 
                wordList[wordCount++] = newWord;

            // YOUR CODE HERE TO LOOK AT THE LENGTH OF THE WORD AND UPDATE HISTOGRAM
            int wordLength = word.length;
            if (word.length() > histogram.length)
                histogram = upSizeHisto( histogram, wordLength );

            histogram[word.length()]++;
            // example if word.length() is 5  then histogram[5] gets increment 
            // BUT IF WORD LENGTH IS >= HISTORGRAM LENGTH 
            // THEN YOU NEED TO FIRST CALL upSizeHisto TO UPSIZE THE HISTOGRAM TO BE OF EXACTLY LENGTH word.length()+1 
            // SIMILAR TO HOW YOU HAD TO UPSIZE WORDLIST


    } //END WHILE INFILE READY
    infile.close();

    wordList = trimArr( wordList, wordCount );
    System.out.println( "After trim, wordList length: " + wordList.length );

    // PRINT WORD LENGTH FREQ HISTOGRAM 
    for ( int i = 0; i < histogram.length ; i++ )
        System.out.println("words of length " + i + ": " + histogram[i]);

} // END main


private static void die( String msg )
{
    System.out.println( msg );
    System.exit(0);
}

private static String[] upSizeArr( String[] oldArr )
{
    String[] newArr = new String[oldArr.length * 2];

    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < oldArr.length; cnt++)
    {
        newArr[cnt] = oldArr[cnt];
    }
    return newArr;
}
private static String[] trimArr( String[] oldArr, int count )
{
    String[] newArr = new String[count];

    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < newArr.length; cnt++)
    {
        newArr[cnt] = oldArr[cnt];
    }
    return newArr;
}

private static int[] upSizeHisto( int[] oldArr, int newLength )
{
    int[] newHisto = new int[newLength];
    for (int cnt = 0;  cnt < newHisto.length; cnt++)
    {
        newHisto[cnt] = oldArr[cnt]; // ERROR HERE, Any help guys?
    }
    return newHisto;
}   
} // END CLASS PROJECT#5
```

One last bit of help I could use is on the last method in the code. I haven't tested it yet due to errors, but if there are any that stick out I could use the help.

Thanks guys.

Comment: i think you are not using any IDE for this. :)

Comment: yup, using Eclipse. It isn't picking up any errors though.

Answer (score 0):

Few mistakes.

1.)

```
  int wordLength = word.length;
```

to

```
  int wordLength = word.length();
```

2.)

```
String newWord = infile.next();
```

to

```
 String newWord = infile.readLine();
```

3.) Add Try Catch

code as below

```
public class Project5 {
    static final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (args.length < 1)
            die("You must type the dictionary filename on cmd line.\n");

        // Here we have declared an int array, called 'histogram' with initial capacity of 0
        // it is a freq counter to word lengths in the file

        int[] histogram = new int[0];

        // Here we have declared an array of String to read the dictionary file into. We use BufferedReader (not Scanner).
        // With each word read in, examine it's length and update word length frequency histogram accordingly

        String[] wordList = new String[INITIAL_CAPACITY];
        int wordCount = 0;

        try {
            BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
            while (infile.ready()) // i.e. while there are more lines of text in the file
            {
                String word = infile.readLine();

                // YOUR CODE HERE TO CHECK TO SEE IF WORDLIST IS FULL
                // IF SO YOU MUST DO AN UPSIZE JUST LIKE LAB#6
                if (wordCount == wordList.length)
                    wordList = upSizeArr(wordList);

                // YOUR CODE HERE to add this word to your list
                String newWord = infile.readLine();
                wordList[wordCount++] = newWord;

                // YOUR CODE HERE TO LOOK AT THE LENGTH OF THE WORD AND UPDATE HISTOGRAM
                int wordLength = word.length();
                if (word.length() > histogram.length)
                    histogram = upSizeHisto(histogram, wordLength);

                histogram[word.length()]++;
                // example if word.length() is 5 then histogram[5] gets increment
                // BUT IF WORD LENGTH IS >= HISTORGRAM LENGTH
                // THEN YOU NEED TO FIRST CALL upSizeHisto TO UPSIZE THE HISTOGRAM TO BE OF EXACTLY LENGTH word.length()+1
                // SIMILAR TO HOW YOU HAD TO UPSIZE WORDLIST
                infile.close();
            } // END WHILE INFILE READY
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        wordList = trimArr(wordList, wordCount);
        System.out.println("After trim, wordList length: " + wordList.length);

        // PRINT WORD LENGTH FREQ HISTOGRAM
        for (int i = 0 ; i < histogram.length ; i++)
            System.out.println("words of length " + i + ": " + histogram[i]);

    } // END main

    private static void die(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private static String[] upSizeArr(String[] oldArr) {
        String[] newArr = new String[oldArr.length * 2];

        for (int cnt = 0 ; cnt < oldArr.length ; cnt++) {
            newArr[cnt] = oldArr[cnt];
        }
        return newArr;
    }

    private static String[] trimArr(String[] oldArr, int count) {
        String[] newArr = new String[count];

        for (int cnt = 0 ; cnt < newArr.length ; cnt++) {
            newArr[cnt] = oldArr[cnt];
        }
        return newArr;
    }

    private static int[] upSizeHisto(int[] oldArr, int newLength) {
        int[] newHisto = new int[newLength];
        for (int cnt = 0 ; cnt < newHisto.length ; cnt++) {
            newHisto[cnt] = oldArr[cnt];
        }
        return newHisto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix, the program compiles, however I am now running into issues with my Histogram upsize method. The portion of it that copies the contents of the old histogram to the new one is bringing an exception error in the command prompt. Any ideas how to fix this?